# Selenium click action not doing anything - just opens browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The code in this post only seems to open up the browser and do nothing else. I would like to use the `move_to_location` action. Currently I am just trying to see if it works so **I am attempting to open a website that allows you to paint, going to a random spot and clicking to create a dot.**

**Why is the code below not doing what I described above?** It just opens the browser at the link provided.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://kleki.com/")
    action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
    action.pointer_action.move_to_location(50, 50).perform()
    action.click().perform()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code and I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\0.py", line 6, in <module>
    action.pointer_action.move_to_location(50, 50).perform()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'pointer_action'
```

The ActionChains class in Selenium does not have a direct method named `pointer_action`.You should use the `move_by_offset` method from the ActionChains class.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://kleki.com/")

# wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# 1 second wait
sleep(1)

action = ActionChains(driver)

# move to a position relative to the current mouse position and click
action.move_by_offset(100, 150).click().perform()

# sleep to see if the mouse clicked
sleep(5)
```

Note: you need to calculate the current position of the mouse and then provide the offset accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are clicking too early. Site takes ~2-3 seconds to be rendered, you need to wait for some key element to be in viewport and only then perform a click.

For example, for header of drawing panel to be visible.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://kleki.com/"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'kl-toolspace-row')))

actions.move_by_offset(50, 100).click().perform()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Both suggested answers work. I gave the answer to the answer that was posted first.